# Remove white background from rasters when background consists of multiple RBG values in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, aerial-photography

I'm trying to remove the background. Usually an easy task, just go to symbology and display the background values as "no color". Unfortunately, the RGB values for the background consist of numerous RGB values. Most are 255, 255, 255, but some of them are different, like 253, 252, 254. So how can I remove the background?

If I had Spatial Analyst, which I don't, I'd use SQL to select and delete all pixels with RGB values above 250, but that's not an option here.

So, I can only think of two options, both of which take too long.

A) Clip the imagery by drawing a polygon

B) Convert the raster to points, so I can select by attributes, then delete the points I don't want before either converting back to raster or clipping the original imagery with the extent of the points

Is there a better option?

Comment: Spatial Analyst doesn't use SQL. Esri calls that syntax Map Algebra. Your slightly non-white pixels are caused by a lossy compression type, probably JPEG. Check you don't have a 4th band (alpha or mask). You could also download GDAL and use the `nearblack` commandline tool - https://gdal.org/programs/nearblack.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Reclassify tool in order to change those odd values to all be 255.

Comment: Reclassify requires Spatial Analyst which the OP does not have a license for.

Comment: I don't have access to spatial analyst, but I do have MapInfo, can I perform the same function in that?